# SPICE model of current amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, spice, model

I am trying to simulate an experimental setup, where the signal of a diode is amplified with a broadband amplifier and then registered by an oscilloscope.

As there are no many information available for the amplifier I was told to simulate it by "using a a simple Spice model with a transfer function with 20 dB gain, a lower cut-off frequency of 1 MHZ and an upper cut-off at 2 GHz".

How could I select the right spice model based on the info given above?

Comment: I'm confused. You are trying to measure a signal with an oscilloscope, but you need a SPICE model? Assuming it's a SPICE simulation, the hint I can give is you have a current amplifier, bandwidth limited with a 2nd order bandpass, and a given gain. Whether it's voltage, or current controlled, you have to know, since "*the signal of a diode*" is rather vague.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thank you and sorry for the confusion. An oscilloscope is used during the real-world experiment which I am trying to simulate with SPICE. Also the signal of the diode is a current pulse. Would you have an amplifier design to recommend based on these?

Comment: The current pulse would be the *input* signal, but the *output* quantity to measure with the oscilloscope is either a voltage or a current. It doesn't matter, though, whichever of these, the hint above stays. I can only say that the current source is readily available as a VCCS (voltage controlled current source). Figuring out the rest is a trivial task now.